# What would be a Philosophical Implications of Relativity Theory?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, relativism

If you were to state one philosophical implication of relativity theory what would you choose and why?

Comment: You'd be better going to a reference, for such a straightforward question. Like https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/spacetime-iframes/

Answer (score 0):

In the world of physics, there are exactly none. If you are talking about things like moral relativism, there are an infinite number of them. As such it is essential to not confuse physics and philosophy when discussing relativity.